# New follow button has `title` attribute and custom tooltip

Tags: bug, follow-posts

The new `follow` button for following posts has a `title` attribute as well as the custom tooltip. There should be one or the other, not both.

Comment: I believe you're asking the same thing as in this main Meta [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345675/562482) to [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/562482).

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks. there is no featured post over here.